# Tasks before capturing your OS

Tags: sysprep, winpe

In addition to one of my previous questions how to make an [Unattended Windows 8.1 installation ISO](https://superuser.com/q/828159/365878), I had the following thought; lets say, your wanting to make a custom Windows installation for a company.

The problem is, in that company they have 5 different models of computers, wich all require different drivers. Can you make some kind of condition to check for the PC model and then install that driver for this specific PC? Or do I then need 5 different images?

You also dont wan't to have any user account on this computer, that's for the user to make one. Is this possible to delete all user's before you sysprep your computer and run WinPE on it?

Comment: What you SHOULD do is have a location on your image (or on a network storage, for example, to save space) with the drivers for all machines (extracted so you have the .inf and supporting files) and you write your unattend.xml file to give the location of the drivers so Windows knows where to look during the setup phases.

Comment: @BigChris And Windows then automaticly knows which drivers to install?

Comment: It should do, yes. When installing devices Windows looks at the driver files and tries to find the hardware ID of the device in the driver file. If the ID is found then that driver can be used for that device. It's not as simple as that, but it's one way that a manufacturer can write one driver for many devices that have (roughly) the same functionality. Imaging and drivers is not an easy task and it involves a lot of learning...!

Comment: @BigChris Alright, and what do you mean by extracting the installation?

Comment: Many drivers are obtained in `.zip` or `.cab` or `.exe` format. Sysprep and unattended installations do not know how to extract these, hence you need to extract the files into a folder. Some driver manufacturers package the drivers inside an exe and they can be almost impossible to extract - in these cases  you may not get a particular device to work without running the exe to install the drivers on each machine separately...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to do this all the time. You don't **need** 5 different images although if you have the storage space, it would be simpler and time effective to just make the image and have that be that.

Assuming that you go with the former option I recommend a variation of what was mentioned before. Setup a local server/storage medium that your WinPE can access. This way each computer (WinPE) can have it's own folder for it's specific drivers.

From here it's quite simple if you are familiar with various parts of WinPE and it sounds like you are. Add drivers to an image using the following commands.

Use [DoubleDriver](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/double_driver.html) to backup any Microsoft or Non-Microsoft drivers. This is super simple and allows you to extract all drivers in the required `.inf` format.

Mount the `install.wim` you want to alter:
`Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:"C:\path\to\install.wim" /index:1 /MountDir:"C:\path\to\MountFolder"`

Inject the specific drivers folder:
`Dism /Add-Driver /Image:"C:\path\to\MountFolder" /Driver:"C:\path\to\DriverFolder /Recurse"`

(If you want to add just one, then point directly to the `.inf` file and remove `/Recurse` flag)

Unmount and save your work:
`Dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:"C:\path\to\MountFolder" /commit`

This can easily be added to the unattended.xml process, via bootable command line or the `startnet.cmd` which is one of the first scripts to be executed during the installation.

Alternatively, you can install a new image to a computer. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> when you're brought to the Windows Setup prompts (Computer name, user name, etc...) and you will be booted into sysprep. From here you can just Restore the drivers file using the first initial DoubleDriver prog. This method may be easier but is has significantly less potential to be automated.

Full documentation on the above suggestion, adding custom commands to `startnet.cmd` and other WAIK goodies.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824972.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The idea with imaging multiple pcs with different model numbers and hardware is to using imaging software like SCCM. With that, you can create a single image that then, through task sequences, grabs additional drivers as it detects what's needed during install. It also installs applications, updates, and a bunch of other stuff like joining to a domain during install. It's a fantastic tool.

Does your company have access to SCCM? If not, you can use WDS (Windows Deployment Services and MDT (Microsoft Deployment Toolkit) to create a similar setup. For free (assuming you already have a Windows 2008 server or higher)

** EDIT **

I don't understand all the down voting. SCCM and WDS/MDT are both legimate and arguably the most Microsoft approved methods for achieving this.

Comment: Alright, but can I do this manually  aswell? If so, what's the process?

Comment: As others have suggested, this method would suffice.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766485(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: As, don't forget to create the network share, assign it read access by everyone, and place the raw .ini and .sys files from the driver in there.